# TL-WN725N not working

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I bought a Raspberry Pi and a TL-WN725N Wi-Fi adapter ("supposed plug and play").

I tried different guides/tutorials to set up wifi dongle, but I did not manage to install it. Especially [(UPDATE) Drivers for TL-WN725N V2 - 3.6.11+ -> 4.0.xx+](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=462982#p462982)

One weird thing is that, it does not appear in `lsusb`:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
```

Do you have any idea to help me ?

Comment: Looks like USB device is not connected properly. Make sure you are using a good power supply with power rating enough to power Rpi's USB devices.

Comment: sometimes you need to install the wifi's firmware file and or kernel module. can you show the result of `dmesg` after pluging the dongle ?

Comment: show us what dmesg shows... in my case with this (v2) wifi dongle, i needed to copy firmware file to preoper directory and it worked like a charm...

Comment: @AymanKhamouma It should appear in `lsusb` even if there is no driver, firmware etc.   That stuff is required to make it work with the OS as a wifi adapter, but not for a USB device to identify itself.  If it cannot do that, no driver or firmware can be applied to it.

Comment: @goldilocks The driver could be disconnecting the dongle if the firmware is not found

Comment: I do not believe a driver *could* disconnect it in this sense, but an easy way to check would be to blacklist or move the driver, then plug it in and out.  *For a driver to do anything with a USB device, it must first be registered through the USB subsystem.*   This will be reported in `dmesg`.  If the driver really has disabled it, not using the driver will leave it listable by `lsusb`.

Comment: Are you sure you're installing the correct version of the driver as explained in the [driver page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=462982#p462982)? `uname -a` will show you a version number (e.g. the 798 in Linux raspi06 4.0.6-v7+ **#798** SMP PREEMPT Tue Jun 23 18:06:01 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux.) You need to be sure you're downloading the version that EXACTLY matches that version number. I have several of these adapters, and once I get the correct version of the driver installed and reboot, they operate normally. Note also that there are different versions for RPi 2B & B.

Comment: @bobstro Again, and evidently I cannot emphasize this enough: **If the device does not show up in `lsusb`, there is no point in trying drivers.  There is nothing to try them on at that point.**  A driver is absolutely not necessary for this purpose, *nor is it ever used for such*.  In order to use a USB driver, the operating system **must** first recognize the device as a particular *kind* of USB device.  If it cannot do that, there is nothing for any driver to access.   The drivers hook into the USB subsystem, NOT the other way around; `lsusb` indicates what's available there.

Comment: Put another way: Any and all functioning USB devices will reveal a make/model ID when attached. No device specific driver is required for this, because all devices use the exact same protocol (the USB protocol).   That is part of what makes them "USB devices".   It is not simply the shape of a plug.  If this communication doesn't happen, nothing more can go on.

Comment: Thanks @dastaan 
I plugged my RPi on the wall instead of using a power strip and it works :D

Comment: @goldilocks: What am I missing? Here's a [capture of the exact procedure I described](http://pastebin.com/Z0iwiiiJ) on a fresh raspian (2015-05-05-raspbian-wheezy.img) install. Are you missing an IME?

Comment: @bobstro Cheers for the missing link!  That driver is indeed in staging for current kernels, and obviously Amyan is correct, it leaves the device completely disabled if it fails.  I was dubious about this because *if* that's by choice, it is a bad and confusing choice to make for people.  Amyan posted out-of-tree driver code to try and prove this, which implies you'd have to install the driver yourself to have this happen.  But if it has been incorporated into the mainline and Raspbian (it has), then it would apply to anyone without having done anything.

Comment: I love that this ended up being a power issue. >_<

Comment: @gerbevar: Did you happen to notice the little 4 color square at the top-right of your screen originally? If so, is it gone now? Interesting that a power strip, not the power adapter made the difference. I think I'd test that strip out before trusting it! @goldilocks: To be clear, my fresh install of Raspbian did not show the device in `lsusb` prior to my installing the driver. I had a lot of frustration with 2 of these adapters prior to finding the driver thread on the RPi forums.

Comment: @dastaan , I guess you should convert your comment as an answer. As it seems it was the right answer.

Comment: @gerbevar Glad to know that it helped. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you've already installed an out-of-tree driver from the thread you linked or still using the stock version, this may explain why the device disappears from `lsusb`. There is a firmware that is supposed to go with the driver, and if that is unavailable or incorrect, [this driver code](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu/blob/master/hal/usb_halinit.c#L1050) might explain why you're not able to see your device with lsusb: The wifi chipset seems to be powered down when `rtl8188eu_hal_deinit()` is called.

I had this problem with this adapter and that is what happened. You can confirm this by examining `dmesg` output.  If you get this kind of error:

```
r8188eu 1-1.5:1.0: Direct firmware load for rtlwifi/rtl8188eufw.bin failed with error -2  
r8188eu 1-1.5:1.0: Firmware rtlwifi/rtl8188eufw.bin not available
```

then you'll need to install the firmware.  If you installed the correct module corresponding to your kernel version, try installing this [firmware](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu/blob/master/rtl8188eufw.bin) in `/lib/firmware/rtlwifi/`.

Otherwise (if you didn't install the corresponding module to your kernel version), you can try [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=62371) or [this one](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=454488).
Please provide the output of `uname -a` and `dmesg` if you don't understand which file should be downloaded.

Comment: I have no wish to get in the middle of a perfectly good argument, but for the record: The pastebin reflects the results of a fresh burn of `2015-05-05-raspbian-wheezy.img` which I then walked over to my RPi 2B and booted off of with a wired Ethernet connection and the TP-Link USB adapter inserted. Once I connected via ssh, I did not physically touch the RPi during the captured session. I did not install any drivers other than the download reflected during the captured session shown in pastebin.

Comment: Yes @bobstro, I was wrong in my first comment. I was just angry my answer was completely rewritten wihout notice. I did not bother to check that's also absolutely right :) I was just mad of goldilocks behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine if this device ever registers.  Start from a fresh boot and then:

```
dmesg | grep 0bda
```

`0bda` is the ID for Realtek, who make the chipsets used in these dongles.
If you see nothing, try `dmesg | grep usb` and see what `idVendor`'s are listed.

The other part of the ID is `idProduct`, which will be either `8176` or `8179` (there are two versions of the TL-WN725N).  The former should have an in-tree<sup>1</sup> driver, try `sudo modprobe 8192cu`.  The latter requires an 8188EU driver which you have to install as per the directions you've already found.

---

<sup>1. The "tree" in "in-tree" and "out-of-tree" refers to the official linux kernel source, which includes most drivers for most things, or at least, most of the drivers that are available for the linux kernel.  However, there are things that aren't included due to licensing issues, or because the driver was not submitted to or was rejected by the people in charge of the kernel.  These tend to be a much bigger hassle.</sup>